# Convert a String value in dataframe to timestamp and Store in Hive

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am reading call records from a file and converting them to columns in a dataframe. How can I convert a column with a string value, which is actually a timestamp in format "yyyymmddhhMMss" to a timestamp before saving that dataframe to hive table? 
I used below snippet but I get null value in the hive table. As I understand I have to specify format i.e., "yyyymmddhhMMss" in which string values exist. But not sure how to do that. I am using spark 2.1.1

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("originTimeStamp",$"originTimeStamp".cast("timestamp")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For converting a String value from dataframe to timestamp, you can use `to_timestamp` function available in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` package. Like this:

**For Spark 2.2 and above**

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("originTimeStamp",to_timestamp($"originTimeStamp", "yyyymmddhhMMss"))
```

**For Spark 2.1 and below**

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("originTimeStamp",unix_timestamp($"originTimeStamp", "yyyymmddhhMMss").cast("timestamp"))
```

It will give you following output:

```
+-------------------+
|    originTimeStamp|
+-------------------+
|2017-01-07 10:06:00|
+-------------------+
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: the thing is that to_timestamp is not available in spark 2.1.1 . Only available function is to_utc_timestamp. Any way forward?

Answer (score 2):

You can use unix_timestamp like below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val df2 = Seq((1, "20180508022659")).toDF("id", "originTimeStamp")
df2.withColumn("originTimeStamp", unix_timestamp($"originTimeStamp", "yyyyMMddHHmmss").cast(TimestampType))
```